# visual studio 2008 dll issue

Tags: visual-studio-2008, qt, dll, browser, plugins

I am new to Visual Studio environment and QT, I am working on developing a browser plugin using QT on visual studio 2008. A 'dll' has been prepared and copied to the plugins folder of the Mozilla firefox and Internet Explorer, it works just fine, I viewed the content using the plugin in the browsers, It all started when I tried to test this on other machine. It doesn't work on the other machine. The machine which I used to develop the dll is 'Windows Vista machine' and the machine I used while testing is 'Windows XP' machine (giving this info if this diff has anything concerned with the issue).

After a little search, I learnt that Runtime Libraries are required for this dll to run. So I installed MSVCREDIST but no luck. Can some body help me in resolving this issue? Any workaround is also appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!!

Krishna

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not quite enough information.

Comment: the dll is used to dislay a qwidget on the browser. I am unable to view it on the other machine while testing. Let me know if any other information is needed,

Comment: How have you solved the issue with QApplication instantiation?

Answer (score 1):

it is possible you are missing the QT run time DLLs
see a list of  DLLs needed for deploying QT applications  [here](http://c9s.blogspot.com/2007/05/qt-runtime-installer-for-windows.html)

if this don't work then try running [dependency](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) walker , on your dll  in the target machine 
if any dll needed to run your own dll is missing the tool will flag it

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to Dependency Walker. I am able to find out which dlls are required to run my dll and added all the required ones. But still my plugin has some problem, Any thoughts??

Comment: you will have to provide more information about the nature of the failure

Comment: The 'dll' when used (on the machine on which it is developed) is able to load the content in the browser. But when used on the other machine, it doesnt. Even after copying the missing dlls, it doesnt show any thing. It just does nothing. An empty box in the place hwere my content has to be displayed. No error. Thanks!!